# Spring security Always redirecting to login when accessing to public pages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

When trying to accessing for first time my webpage in Spring, by some reason (I think not from the configuration class) Spring Security is always redirecting me to the login page, even if I tried to make it public.

Here's what the configuration sheet look like, just in case:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    RepositoryUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10, new SecureRandom());
    }
    //Method that allow us to configure access to webpages.
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //Validating user...
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        //Public pages
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                             "/login",
                             "/register",
                             "/locale",
                             "/games",
                             "/js/*",
                             "/css/*")
                .permitAll();
//        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        //        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("login").permitAll();
//        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").permitAll();
//        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/locale").permitAll();
//        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/bets").permitAll();



         // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").permitAll();

        //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/games").permitAll();

        //Public endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/locale/**","/api/game").permitAll();
        //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/game").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").permitAll();

        //Authenticated pages
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/locale").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        //Authenticated endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/bet").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/bet").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/bet").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");

        //Private pages and endpoints (the rest of them)
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");

        // Login form
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");
        http.formLogin().usernameParameter("username");
        http.formLogin().passwordParameter("password");
        http.formLogin().failureUrl("/loginerror");
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/logged");
         // Logout
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        // Disable CSRF at the moment
        http.csrf().disable();

    }
```

Here the RestSecurityConfig:

```
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    RepositoryUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10, new SecureRandom());
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

And here's the UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class RepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByName(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String role : user.getRoles()) {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getName(),
                user.getPass(), roles);
    }
}
```

Any sugestion? thank you

Comment: You code is contradictory, you first did `.antMatchers("/","/login","/register","/locale","/games", "/js/*","/css/*").permitAll()` but then `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/locale").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");`

Comment: I removed that sentence and nothing, still asking for log in :/